# Direct Line API example in .NET

Tags: c#, azure, botframework

I've created a bot in .NET using the Azure Bot Framework and I've tested successfully in the emulator.

I want to create a local .net console application that can listen to my bot conversations using the Direct Line API and perform simple tasks as well as respond in the conversation.

I can't find a complete example of how to begin poling the message endpoint to listen for messages and then respond.  I've scoured the original Azure documentation and I can't find anything.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-concepts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of the Direct Line API? Can someone please provide some very simple sample code that begins listening for conversation activity, and then handles activity when detected?

Comment: Can you specify what you want this client to do? You can [use the API to retrieve activities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#http-get), but most folks use [Web Chat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) as the client to converse with the bot. I'm not exactly sure what you're asking for.

Comment: I interact with my bot through Slack.  I want to send a slack message to my bot that will initiate a conversation with a client app with Direct Line API on a remote server. That client app would be able to perform tasks and respond in slack via the bot.  I got the client app running with Direct Line and I can initiate conversations with my bot, but I can't get my bot to initiate conversations with my client app.

Comment: Sounds like you need [proactive messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following example fits your requirement:
A bot and an additional controller that is used to send proactive messages to the bot, as shown in the following illustration.
[image]

More information please refer to:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp